# Authorize nested controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan, cancancan

I have this setup:

`routes.rb`:

```
resources :orders, only: [] do
  # many other member actions
  # ...
  namespace :confirm, module: :orders do
    controller :confirm do
      get :cash
    end
  end
end
```

`orders/confirm_controller.rb`:

```
class Orders::ConfirmController < ApplicationController
  load_and_authorize_resource class: Order,
                              id_param: :order_id,
                              instance_name: :order

  def cash
  end
end
```

`ability.rb`:

```
can :cash, Order do |order|
  order.buyer == user
end
```

The idea is: since `OrdersController` already overloaded with almost 20 actions, I want move new actions to nested controller. The code above is working but I feel that this part:

```
  load_and_authorize_resource class: Order,
                              id_param: :order_id,
                              instance_name: :order
```

can be done easier. And ability that I have is for parent controller and not namespaced to nested controller, so if someone define `cash` method in `OrdersController` same ability will be used, what is not good. So is there any better way?

Comment: I think you should really read this and organise your controllers a bit better: http://jeromedalbert.com/how-dhh-organizes-his-rails-controllers/ it helped me!

Comment: @coorasse I know this and I follow this. But finally I came up to this question.